# Duplicate and Randomize the position of items within a list

Tags: java

I have got an Arraylist of integers in java called list which contains 7 elements `[12, 13, 17, 18, 19, 11, 20]`. I want to copy the same elements two times in the end of the list with random order, so in the end to have the same integers three times (so in total 21 items), however, with random order for every 7 items. How can i do so in Java?

Comment: I don't get your question, are you going to ends up with a 21 int list or you are just copying somewhere else the numbers that you randomly pick?

Comment: does it matter if we duplicate them all first then randomise them or do you want it as you're duplicating it randomizes at the same time.

Comment: you can copy elements to another arraylist on which you will perform `Collections.shuffle(copyList);` then you will append these shuffled copies to the original arraylist.

Comment: How can I copy three times the shuffle lists?

Comment: Have you tried googling these questions? There are tons of results for each part of your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the list and shuffle for each iteration.

```
final int DUPLICATE_AMOUNT = 3; // if you want the created array 3 times as big as the original

List<Integer> list = getMyList(); //original list 
List<Integer> fullRandom = new ArrayList<Integer>();
fullRandom.addAll(list);
for (int i = 1; i < DUPLICATE_AMOUNT; i++) {
    List<Integer> randomList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    randomList.addAll(list);
    Collections.shuffle(randomList);
    fullRandom.addAll(randomList);
}
```

Comment: My initial list is an ArrayList. Is it possible to convert it first into the List in order to perform addAll?

Comment: I find your use of `DUPLICATE_AMOUNT` with `int i=1` misleading, although technically correct. 1) "duplicate" could either describe the additional copies or the whole (as you intended) 2) people are so used to `int i=0` that they might miss your `int i=1` and misunderstand. There's nothing wrong with your answer, but I think `ADDITIONAL_COPIES=2` + `int i=0` would have been more clear.

Comment: @konstantin `ArrayList` is an implementation of `List`, there's no need to cast.

Comment: @Aaron then why I have issues with addAll?

Comment: @konstantin It's just good practice to use the interface and not the implementation. So whenever possible, you should use the interface.

Comment: @konstantin I don't know, I tested the answer and [it worked just fine](https://ideone.com/noLXqk)

Comment: @stealthjong You could maybe initialize the arrayList directly with the entries of the list by using `new ArrayList<>(list)` to make the code a bit more compact.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy your list two times and shuffle it:

```
List<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<>(yourList);

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
  Collections.shuffle(tempList, new Random(System.nanoTime()));
  yourList.addAll(tempList);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// init your list
List<Integer> initialList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
initialList.add(new Integer(12));
initialList.add(new Integer(13));
initialList.add(new Integer(14));
initialList.add(new Integer(15));
// create a new list that'll contain your random numbers
List<Integer> tripleList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// triple your values
tripleList.addAll(initialList); 
tripleList.addAll(initialList);
tripleList.addAll(initialList);
// randomize their order
Collections.shuffle(tripleList);
// until is empty get the top of the list with this command. 
//A random number among your list
tripleList.remove(0);
```

Comment: In newer Java versions, the `Integer` constructor is *deprecated*. Use `Integer::valueOf` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Collections.shuffle()` and call it twice for the initial data list:

```
private List<Integer> shufflePositions(List<Integer> data) {
    Collections.shuffle(data);
    return data;
}

public void solve() {
    List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<>();
    data.add(12);
    data.add(13);
    data.add(17);
    data.add(18);
    data.add(19);
    data.add(11);
    data.add(20);
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.addAll(data);
    result.addAll(shufflePositions(new ArrayList<>(data)));
    result.addAll(shufflePositions(new ArrayList<>(data)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(12, 13, 17, 18, 19, 11, 20));

for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {

    List<Integer> IntegersClone = new ArrayList<>(integers);

    Collections.shuffle(IntegersClone);

    integers.addAll(IntegersClone);
}

//Output : [12, 13, 17, 18, 19, 11, 20, 19, 17, 12, 11, 20, 18, 13, 20, 12, 19, 11, 18, 13, 13, 11, 17, 18, 19, 12, 17, 20]
System.out.print(integers);
```